# CDI Beans module deployment failed: couldn't start owb context

Tags: java-8, junit4, eclipse-luna, openejb, apache-tomee

I have a Maven project. The build runs properly including tests. But when I run the tests only using Eclipse Luna, then the tests fail:

```
javax.enterprise.event.ObserverException: Caught Exception while handling event object with type : org.apache.webbeans.portable.events.discovery.AfterBeanDiscoveryImpl
...
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.webbeans.container.InjectableBeanManager.getInjectionTargetFactory(Ljavax/enterprise/inject/spi/AnnotatedType;)Ljavax/enterprise/inject/spi/InjectionTargetFactory;
    at com.sun.faces.util.cdi11.CDIUtilImpl.createHelperBean(CDIUtilImpl.java:76)
    at com.sun.faces.flow.FlowCDIExtension.afterBeanDiscovery(FlowCDIExtension.java:120)
    ... 60 more
INFO - Undeploying app: .../classpath.ear
org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Creating application failed: /home/schnikow/projects/barbuchon2/BarbuchonKernel-2.0r0b-SNAPSHOT/classpath.ear: couldn't start owb context

(full stack trace is too long, I can provide it if needed)
```

I've add the needed JVM argument (`-javaagent:/usr/devel/apache-tomee-webprofile-1.7.1/lib/openejb-javaagent.jar`) in the launch configuration. I may miss something trivial, but I haven't any idea, what.

I use Eclipse Luna and Tomee embedded EJB container running on Java 8 virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

it seems you use mojarra, is it a CDI 1.0 compatible version or 1.1 (only TomEE 2 will be CDI 1.1/1.2 compatible)